# "xdg-open" Won't Open Local html File

Tags: html, ubuntu

Background: I'm super new, and I'm trying to open a local html file with `xdg-open` but it ends in an error instead.

Using `xdg-open` will open other file extensions in their default programs: `.txt` in Notepad, image files in my image viewer, `.pdf` files in Adobe, and even urls in Chrome. BUT if I try to open an `.html` file, I get the following error:

```
$ xdg-open index.html 
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "/tmp/fileYgDEg1.html"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Any suggestions for solutions? I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04.